# Symfony commands execution error: The environment "= " contains invalid characters

Tags: docker, symfony, environment-variables, command, apple-m1

I'm encountering a strange problem on symfony 5.4 when executing every command , made by me or of the framework like cache:clear , i instantly recieve this error:

```
In Kernel.php line 418
The environment "= " contains invalid characters, it can only contain characters allowed in PHP class names.
```

Scenario:
Framework: Symfony 5.5
PHP version: 8.2
Architecture: MacOS M1
The program run inside a docker container on the local machine.

The problem show only when i run a symfony command, but if i call the normal symfony controllers via browser or postman, they are able to correctly access to the env variables , connect to external database e return correctly the data.

Can an error like this be the consequence of a crash of somekind ? and if yes how can debug that if  now error exept che kernel exception show in the terminal or the logs.

Cant find a clue of this strange behaviour.
Tx for your help

I've tryed the following tests

- TEST1 rebuild the docker imager by docker-compose down,
  docker-compose build docker-compose up
- TEST2 rebuild on another
  maching ( another Mac M1 )
- TEST3 try controller and they works
  correctly event if they depends by the env variables to works like
  access to a db and return datas.
- TEST4 i created a controller that
  print a system parameter depending from a env variable and make it
  print parameter and is printed ok

Comment: How you are calling env variable in symfony command?
If you are using `$_ENV['SAMPLE_VAR']` then it will work fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're executing bin/console with `--env = .env.dev.local` flag.

The environment name should be only `dev`, not `.env.dev`.
Change your `APP_ENV` variable (or your `--env` flag) to `dev` and remove spaces.

```
--env=dev
```

Answer (score -1):

in the `.env` key:value should be sth like this

```
APP_ENV=dev # or APP_ENV="dev"
APP_NAME=Demo
DATABASE_URL=mysql://username:my_Pass@localhost:3306/DB_nameserverVersion=5.7
```

php bin/console cache:clear
and then restart the server

Comment: Tx , i can confirm you that my env file is pretty similar , i've an .env.dev.local too with che override to the env variables of the database for example.

The controllers read correctly the env but the commands , all the commands crash in the way i described.